# Setting ASP.NET MVC ControllerFactory has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm trying to have my ASP.NET MVC2 controllers built using StructureMap but ASP.NET doesn't seem to remember that I've called `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory` in my Global.asax file.

Specifically I get the error that my controller has no parameterless constructor. The stack trace reveals that my custom `ControllerFactory` was never actually executed.

Here is my call to the method that should tell ASP.NET which ControllerFactory to use:

```
Sub Application_Start()

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(GetType(StructureMapControllerFactory))

    BootStrapper.RegisterDependencies()

End Sub
```

And here's the exception that I receive.

```
[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
  System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
  System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
  System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
  System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
  System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
```

Why is ASP.NET forgetting which ControllerFactory to use?

Answer (score 2):

How is your StructureMapControllerFactory defined? Does it have a default constructor?

If not, try using that second overload of the SetControllerFactory method:

```
// First create the controllerFactory instance...

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

Comment: Hi there. I managed to fix this by created a new Visual Studio project and copied the code into it from my other project. Everything just worked after that.

The code itself wasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your controllerFactory before you RegisterRoutes...