# ASP.NET MVC - setting custom IControllerFactory has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I really dont understand what I'm doing wrong here - for some reason the `IControllerFactory` i register is not being used, and I end up with a `System.ArgumentException`:

> Type 'Company.WebApi.Controllers.AController' does not have a default
>   constructor
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)  at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

In Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //DI-setup
    var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());

    //set custom controller factory
    var controllerFactory = container.Resolve<IControllerFactory>();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

    //register cors
    container.Resolve<ICorsConfig>().RegisterCors(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    //routes
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

My `IControllerFactory` is based on this article http://keyvan.io/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc and is implemented as following

```
public class ControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

        public ControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if(container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

            _container = container;
        }

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerName");

            var componentName = GetComponentNameFromControllerName(controllerName);

            return _container.Resolve<IController>(componentName);
        }

        public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            _container.Release(controller);
        }

        static string GetComponentNameFromControllerName(string controllerName)
        {
            var controllerNamespace = typeof (CrudController<>).Namespace;
            return string.Format("{0}.{1}Controller", controllerNamespace, controllerName);
        }
    }
```

I've been staring at this for hours, and really can't see why this isn't working. When debugging the `ControllerFactory` is never hit in any method except the constructor. Anyone see whats wrong or missing here?

([Setting ASP.NET MVC ControllerFactory has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952187/setting-asp-net-mvc-controllerfactory-has-no-effect) does not answer my question)

**Edit 1 - Controller**

```
    public class AController : CrudController<AModel>
    {
        public AController(IAHandler aHandler) : base(aHandler)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetByUser(string aId)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public abstract class CrudController<T> : ApiController
        where T : IModel, new()
    {
        protected CrudController(ICrudHandler<T> handler)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(T input)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(T input)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2 - Installer**

```
    public sealed class WebWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        private bool _installComplete;

        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            if(_installComplete)
                return;

            //register self for reuse
            container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorInstaller>().Instance(this));

            //controller factory
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IControllerFactory>().ImplementedBy<ControllerFactory>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

            //Handlers
            container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<AHandler>().InSameNamespaceAs<AHandler>().WithService.
                    DefaultInterfaces());

            //Models
            container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<AModel>().InSameNamespaceAs<AModel>().WithService.Self());

            //DI
            container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
            container.Register(Component.For<IDependencyResolver>().ImplementedBy<WindsorDependencyResolver>());

            //Controllers
            container.Register(Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<AController>()
                .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                .LifestyleScoped());

            //repositories
            container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<ARepository>().InSameNamespaceAs<ARepository>().WithService.
                    DefaultInterfaces());

            //cors
            container.Register(Component.For<ICorsConfig>().ImplementedBy<CorsConfig>());

            _installComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you register `ControllerFactory` type with the container?

Comment: I just looked at the link you gave in the question. In the link, the custom controller factory is set on this line `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));`. You are trying to resolve `IControllerFactory` instance using the container but nothing has been registered with container first (unless you have missed some details out)

Comment: Hi Suhas, thanks for taking an interrest. Everything is registered within the line `var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());`As I mentioned the constructor of `ControllerFactory` is hit when debugging, proving that the resolve executes corretly

Comment: Could you show your controller class that throws this exception?

Comment: Where you are mapping IControllerFactory to it's corresponding impl (ControllerFactory)? I don't now about Windsor, does it automatically resolve it?

Comment: I'm just making an educated guess here. Should you be registering the routes before setting the controller factory?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Hi, please see **Edit 1** above

Comment: @Mark Hi, please see **Edit 2** above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error messages in your question it looks like you actually want to register WebAPI controllers.  It's important to note that these are not the same as MVC controllers, and do not use the same controller factory (which you are trying to use).

See Mark Seeman's post [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API with Castle Windsor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx) for details of how to do this for Web API controllers.